# How to translate a country list in a django views.py?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-countries

I am using django and the standard internationalization package as showed in the : [excellent marina mele tuto.](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/internationalization-localization-languages-time-zones)

In a user's form  on web and mobile i have to show a list of country names in the **user's language**.

To create the country list, i intend to use django-country it seems easy and well documented.

I could do one API, no template, to request the list of countries.

But How to translate this country list in the views.py ?

Any example would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about [django-countries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-countries)? You shouldn't need to do anything other than make sure that your user's language is activated `translation.activate(language)`, which is also handled in Django's middleware if you're using `i18n_urlpatterns`. From there, it will use the builtin gettext machinery to retrieve the country name in the user's language.

You can use the country objects in a serializer with `django_countries.serializer_fields.CountryField`, or in a view with

```
from django_countries import countries
from django.http import JsonResponse

def countries_list(request):
    for code, name in list(countries):
        print(code, name)

    return JsonResponse({
        code: name for code, name in list(countries)
    })
```

Or however you like. In a template:

```
{% load countries %}
{% get_country 'BR' as country %}
{{ country.name }}
```

should work, as long as your user's language is activated.

Comment: In a template, it works perfectly.  But i do not have template. As the code must run on mobile app & web, i code some API. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still looking for how to do it. It was pretty easy, in large part thanks to @slurms explanation and reading through the relevant [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language) (though it took me some time to find them). It's actually very straightforward.

First, you will need to add the necessary settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
    ...
]
USE_I18N = True
```

Then get the language from your request or other parameter, and the translating can begin e.g.:

```
from django.utils import translation
from django_countries import countries


def foo_bar(language):
   translation.activate(language)
   return [(translation.gettext(country.name), country.code) for country in countries]
```

This is all you need!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation), the library is used to do translation from your model data.

Otherwise if you want to translate a list of countries, you can construct a new list and use the builtin django translation tools on each item in the list.

Comment: It seems good...i am looking for code examples to really understand

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i am using a simple array

```
TranslatedCountries = {
'france':   { 
                'en':   u'france',
                'fr':   u'france',
                },

'belgium':  {
                'en':   u'belgium',
                'fr':   u'belgique',
                },
'spain':    {
                 'en':  u'spain',
                 'fr':  u'espagne',
                },
'morocco':  {
                 'en':  u'morocco',
                 'fr':  u'maroc',
                },
```

}

and i access it:

```
try:
            CCC = TranslatedCountries[test_country.lower()][user_language.lower()]
        except :
            print "The country %s is not defines for the language %s" % (test_country.lower(),user_language.lower() )
            CCC = test_country

print CCC
```

I hope someone wil give us a simpler, faster and cleaner solution.
Thanks you for you help.
Al